# What is a ref strategy in a gitlab ci pipeline file?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using Gitlab and added a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to trigger my pipeline. What I don't understand is the purpose of [refs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyrefsexceptrefs) when used in combination with the `only` keyword. Here is an example I use:

```
only:
     - /^newlib.*$/
```

But in another example I found this:

```
only:
    refs:
      - master
```

The documentation only states:

> ```
> The refs strategy can take the same values as the simplified only/except configuration.
> ```

Can anyone share some light on this? What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference between your two examples. As you quoted the docs yourself:

> The refs strategy can take the same values as the simplified only/except configuration.

That said, you only need to use `refs` if you also want to use the other options: [`changes`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges), [`kubernetes`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlykubernetesexceptkubernetes) and [`variables`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyvariablesexceptvariables).

The docs has some [examples using multiple options](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-advanced) such as:

```
test:
  script: npm run test
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - schedules
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /run-end-to-end-tests/
    kubernetes: active
```

If you remove the `refs` you will get an invalid yml file

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!